# parsing multidimensional javascript json array with php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, parsing

I have the following multidimensional javascript array:

[My js array](https://pastebin.com/EJ7cpkmv)

and I want to parse it and return some values from it (name and url)

but when cleaning it up a bit `$jsonData = str_replace('var stations = ','' ,$jsonDataUrl);` and trying to parse it as json with `json_decode($jsongoeshere)`, the parser returned error 4 even if this [URL](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html) had told me 
that The JSON input is valid in JavaScript.

So now I am a bit lost on how to parse it.

Comment: I guess your array is an array of json. So try json decoding it first and then clean it up. Update the question if anything changed

Comment: Your code sample implies that you're attempting to run `str_replace` on the URL, as opposed to the contents contained at the URL. Also, you left the semicolon at the end of the JS before parsing with PHP. Finally, you are missing double quotes around many, many property names.

Answer (score 1):

`quoted object property name expected` is your error.

Your JSON string is not valid, object property names must be quoted.

This

```
{
        "aland": [
        {
            name: "Ålands Radio",
            logo: "stations/images-europe/aland/Ålands Radio.png",
            url: "http://194.110.182.131:8000/stream.ogg"
        },
...
```

Should be

```
{
        "aland": [
        {
            "name": "Ålands Radio",
            "logo": "stations/images-europe/aland/Ålands Radio.png",
            "url": "http://194.110.182.131:8000/stream.ogg"
        },
...
```

These JSON validators give you the correct error.

https://jsonlint.com/  &  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Also, what @JJAulde said is true.

You have a semicolon at the end of your JSON string that will cause the parse to fail. You need to `rtrim` or `str_replace` it like you did with `var stations =`

Comment: Property quoting is only one of the problems. The trailing semicolon (`;`) is another.